# How to pass a "target" property to a Vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How can I change the `src` attribute on my component on error?

This is the template code:

```
<author
   v-bind:thumbnail="author.thumbnailUrl"
   v-bind:nama="author.id"
   v-bind:deskripsi="author.title"
   @error="pplUrlAlt"
/>
```

And this is the method that attempts to to change `src` on error:

```
pplUrlAlt(event) {
    event.target.thumbnail = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518241353330-0f7941c2d9b5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=c71d179decac2be7a2c39f8252487f97&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1225&q=80"
}
```

Before I switched to components it used to work when I changed the URL of a broken `img` element, but now it doesn't work anymore. How can I implement this on my component using `props`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. Remember Vue is "data-driven", so instead of trying to manipulate the HTML directly, focus on composing your components. When you manipulate the component's data, any changes will automatically reflect on your HMTL.

This is how I would approach a similar problem:

```
<template>
    <author
       v-bind:thumbnail="error ? errorThumbnail : author.thumbnailUrl"
       v-bind:nama="author.id"
       v-bind:deskripsi="author.title"
       @error="setError"
    />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            error: false,
            errorThumbnail: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518241353330-0f7941c2d9b5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=c71d179decac2be7a2c39f8252487f97&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1225&q=80'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setError () {
            this.error = true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Obviously this is a simplification of what your component probably looks like, but the gist of it is: the component should be aware of the fact that an error occurred, and render the child component differently, doing so by changing its prop value. This respects the communication paradigm of Vue: children communicate with parents via events, parents communicate with children via props.